# attracting set dynamical systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There are some definitions about attracting set, but one of them is confusing for me. First, definitions:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
1) \textrm{flow:} \enspace \phi_t({\bf x}) \\ 
2) \textrm{for a subset} \enspace M: \enspace \phi_t(M) = \bigcup\limits_{{\bf x} \in M} \phi_t({\bf x}) \\
3) M \enspace \textrm{is a trapping region if it is compact and } \phi_t(M) \subset int(M), t>0 \\
4) A \enspace \textrm{is an attracting set if there exist a trapping region 
 } M \enspace \textrm{such that} \enspace A \subset M \enspace \textrm{and}\\
A=\bigcap_{t>0} \phi_t(M)
\end{array}
$$

Suppose you have a system in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a fixed point $P$ that is a sink. Consider a small neighborhood $U$ of $P$, with two points of it, namely $(x_0,y_0) \ne (x_1,y_1)$, that belong to different orbits $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_1$ respectively. By uniqueness $\Gamma_0 \cap \Gamma_1 = \emptyset$.

If the limit $t \to \infty$ is allowed in the previous definition then $\Gamma_0 \cap \Gamma_1 = \{P\}$, which is the attracting set, as expected.

Coud you help me to understand this definition? Thank you

Comment: You have to define all the terms you use. What is $\phi (t,M)$?

Comment: Thank you Kavi, I have included some definitions

Comment: So which is the definition that you are confused about?

Comment: I have problems with number 4). I think that the intersection is empty, and below 4) I gave an example.

Comment: So I think the confusion here is that $\phi_t(M)$ will be another set (i.e other region in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We aren't intersecting individual orbits. So essentially if you were to think of all solutions starting at some point in $M$ then evolving the system forward by $t$, then $\phi_t(M)$ is where all those points have now ended up after some time $t$.

Comment: So in your example where $P$ is a sink and say we consider some closed ball, $B$, around $P$ such that all points starting in $B$ will tend to $P$, then for each $t$, the set $\phi_t(B)$ will sort of "shrink" as we move along in time.

Comment: I understand your idea, is the definition that appears in Perko's book:
A closed invariant set $A$ is an attracting set if there is some neighborhood $U$ of $A$ such that for all ${\bf x} \in U$, $\phi_t ({\bf x}) \in U$ for all $t \ge 0$, and $\phi_t({\bf x}) \to A$ as $t \to \infty$. This definition makes sense for me. How could see that this is equivalent to 4), in particular why appear the intersection symbol in 4)?

Comment: I believe we can see these as being equivalent? If we consider a point in the intersection, then that means that for some initial condition $x \in M$ that as $t \to \infty$ that eventually $\phi_t(x) \in A$.